# Drupal Views Bonus Pack export issue

Tags: xml, drupal, export, drupal-views

In trying to solve the problem of getting data from Drupal into XML, I found the Views Bonus Pack module, which with a little figuring out works great.  Except...

When setting the Style property in the Basic settings of Feed view to XML file no items show up unless I am authenticated.  If I log in, I see all the entries.  If I log out, I see only

```
<xml>
<node/>
</xml>
```

The Access setting is set to unrestricted in both the Defaults and the Feed view.

Anybody have any ideas as to how to fix this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: xml is not easy to import, i assume only customized code can do it...

Comment: Hi Nikit, I'm not looking to import XML, only to export it.  I.e. take the data from a custom content type and return XML when someone accesses the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your anonymous user can't see  any node. Try to read a content when you're not aunthenticated.

Comment: Yes, good thought, but I have checked for that.  When I view other nodes I get all the content.

Comment: I still think this is a permission problem. Maybe something with content permission.

Comment: Hmmm, OK. I'll take an extra look at the permissions outside of the Views.

Comment: Yup, it turned out to be a content_permissions issue.  Thanks for the pointer.